# TesNG does not run even after trying everything

Tags: testng

I have literally tried everything to run TestNG but still it doesn't works.
Below are the details of my run -

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

```
package Testiwthng;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class NewTest{

@Test

public void f() {

    System.out.println("Hello World");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        String pageTitle= driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(pageTitle);
        Assert.assertEquals(pageTitle,"Google");
  Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
```

}
}

This is how my xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" >
<test name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="Testiwthng.NewTest"/>
  </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Everything looks good to me.
Can anyone help out here. I have literally ran out of options here.
If I give the wrong class path, it gives an error, so it does try to read the class path. The problem is, it never executes the class.

Comment: please mark an answer to the question if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `@Test` from junit instead of TestNG.

Comment: Yes for sure. Is there anything i need to do to accept the answer?

Comment: @vips, [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/349248). You can also upvote juherr's answer (arrow up). I just did. This is your privilege and is very good for answerers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@Test` from junit instead of TestNG

Replace

`import org.junit.Test;`

with

`import org.testng.annotations.Test;`